# Scanning a rest api web service using acunetix

Tags: web-services, security, http-headers, scanning

I have a request post the send in acunetix scanner , but don't know how to send it and how to specify the post method , because when i added the headers in the "custom headers" option in acunetix scanner i got the get method sendded instead of the post one .

This is my request to send:

```
POST /Test/new_date HTTP/1.1

Host: app-test-ext

Content-Type: application/json

Cache-Control: no-cache

{UserName:test01,Password:poper}
```